# How can i get the Logged in user Name of Client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i get the LoggedIn  in user Name of Client machine

without client providing the useid and password...
(wjen the users visits the page i need to get In which user Id he/she loggedIn)

I tried

```
string clientMachineName;
clientMachineName = (Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName);
Response.Write(clientMachineName);
```

Comment: your code reads as Machine name and you are asking about logged in Username, which is the one you are interested ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta  I need to read client machine Login UserName when client visits my page..

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this in a LAN or WAN environment? What OS's are you looking to do this on? What browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a domain environment you could enable Windows Authentication which will allow the users to bypass explicitly logging on in favor of NTLM authentication. IE and Chrome work well with this out of the box, FF has a config setting for it.

EDIT

If you only care about browsers/OSs that support ActiveX then you can get it using Javascript with specific ActiveX privileges (from [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3441878.htm)):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network"); 
alert(WinNetwork.UserName); 
//--> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Might be its work as per your requirement

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
```

if Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") Returns Empty String in ASP.NET
[Microsoft Guidline for that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306359)

Comment: Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] returning empty sting.. bz page is not windows autheticated..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Request.LogonUserIdentity** for getting client details.

Response.Write(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name);

Comment: `Request.LogonUserIdentity` is only valid if the user was authenticated against the website. The OP is looking for a way to get the Username of the user on the client machine without requiring credentials to be authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) have been depreciated for C# in some instances.

If so, you'll need to do it this way:

```
string login = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

If you really want to use ServerVariables, keep in mind they are **CaSe Sensitive** in C#. The correct casing is almost always *UPPER*, and here is the list of them:

[List of ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx)